# SpringBootTest Not found user failed

Tags: spring, spring-boot, junit, spring-test

I want to test `BoardService.java`, a class that has a `saveBoard()` function that creates a `Board` with `User` and `Category` as foreign keys. So I created `BoardServiceTest.java` and wrote this test in `createBoardTest()`. First of all, `User` and `Category` are needed, so users and categories are saved using `@Autowired` repository, and after that, `boardRepository.save()` is executed. However, it says that the user cannot be found. I want to know why. Thank you.

There's my code.

#### [BoardServiceTest.java]

```java
package com.example.boardprojct.service;

import com.example.boardprojct.data.dto.*;
import com.example.boardprojct.repository.BoardRepository;
import com.example.boardprojct.repository.CategoryRepository;
import com.example.boardprojct.repository.UserRepository;
import org.assertj.core.api.Assertions;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;

import javax.transaction.Transactional;

@SpringBootTest
@Transactional
public class BoardServiceTest {
    @Autowired
    private BoardRepository boardRepository;

    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    @Autowired
    private CategoryRepository categoryRepository;

    @Autowired
    private BoardService boardService;

    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;

    @Autowired
    private CategoryService categoryService;

    @Test
    public void createBoard() throws Exception {
        UserResponseDto userResponseDto = userService.saveUser(UserDto.builder().id(12L).username("apple").email("apple@apple.com").password("password").build());
        CategoryResponseDto categoryResponseDto = categoryService.saveCategory(CategoryDto.builder().id(12L).name("MainCategory").build());

        assert userResponseDto != null;
        assert categoryResponseDto != null;

        BoardDto boardDto = BoardDto.builder()
                .id(12L)
                .title("Title")
                .content("<div>Content</div>")
                .userId(12L)
                .categoryId(12L).build();
        BoardResponseDto dto = BoardResponseDto.builder()
                .id(12L)
                .title("Title")
                .content("<div>Content</div>")
                .build();

        BoardResponseDto boardResponseDto = boardService.saveBoard(boardDto);

        Assertions.assertThat(boardResponseDto.getId()).isEqualTo(dto.getId());
        Assertions.assertThat(boardResponseDto.getTitle()).isEqualTo(dto.getTitle());
        Assertions.assertThat(boardResponseDto.getContent()).isEqualTo(dto.getContent());
        System.out.println(boardResponseDto);
    }
}
```

#### [BoardServiceImpl]

```java
package com.example.boardprojct.service;

import com.example.boardprojct.data.domain.Board;
import com.example.boardprojct.data.domain.Category;
import com.example.boardprojct.data.domain.User;
import com.example.boardprojct.data.dto.BoardDto;
import com.example.boardprojct.data.dto.BoardResponseDto;
import com.example.boardprojct.repository.BoardRepository;
import com.example.boardprojct.repository.CategoryRepository;
import com.example.boardprojct.repository.UserRepository;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import java.util.Optional;

@Service
public class BoardServiceImpl implements BoardService {

    final private BoardRepository boardRepository;
    private final UserRepository userRepository;
    private final CategoryRepository categoryRepository;

    @Autowired
    public BoardServiceImpl(BoardRepository boardRepository, UserRepository userRepository, CategoryRepository categoryRepository) {
        this.boardRepository = boardRepository;
        this.userRepository = userRepository;
        this.categoryRepository = categoryRepository;
    }

    @Override
    public BoardResponseDto saveBoard(BoardDto boardDto) throws Exception {
        // find user
        Optional<User> optionalUser = userRepository.findById(boardDto.getUserId());
        if(optionalUser.isEmpty())
            throw new Exception("User not found");
        User user = optionalUser.get();

        // find category
        Optional<Category> optionalCate = categoryRepository.findById(boardDto.getCategoryId());
        if(optionalCate.isEmpty())
            throw new Exception("Category not found");
        Category category = optionalCate.get();
        // save board
        Board board = Board.builder()
                .id(boardDto.getId())
                .title(boardDto.getTitle())
                .content(boardDto.getTitle())
                .user(user)
                .category(category)
                .build();

        // check is id duplicated
        Optional<Board> foundBoard = boardRepository.findById(boardDto.getId());
        if(foundBoard.isPresent()) return null;

        Board savedBoard = boardRepository.save(board);

        // response
        BoardResponseDto boardResponseDto = BoardResponseDto.builder()
                .id(savedBoard.getId())
                .title(savedBoard.getTitle())
                .content(savedBoard.getContent())
                .user(savedBoard.getUser())
                .category(savedBoard.getCategory())
                .createdAt(savedBoard.getCreatedAt())
                .updatedAt(savedBoard.getUpdatedAt())
                .build();
        return boardResponseDto;
    }

    @Override
    public BoardResponseDto updateBoard(BoardDto boardDto) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void deleteBoard(Long id) {

    }
}
```

And this is console log

```
ser not found
java.lang.Exception: User not found
    at com.example.boardprojct.service.BoardServiceImpl.saveBoard(BoardServiceImpl.java:35)
    at com.example.boardprojct.service.BoardServiceTest.createBoard(BoardServiceTest.java:55)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:104)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:577)
    at org.junit.platform.commons.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:725)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.MethodInvocation.proceed(MethodInvocation.java:60)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain$ValidatingInvocation.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:131)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.intercept(TimeoutExtension.java:149)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.interceptTestableMethod(TimeoutExtension.java:140)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.interceptTestMethod(TimeoutExtension.java:84)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker$ReflectiveInterceptorCall.lambda$ofVoidMethod$0(ExecutableInvoker.java:115)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.lambda$invoke$0(ExecutableInvoker.java:105)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain$InterceptedInvocation.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:106)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:64)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.chainAndInvoke(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:45)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.invoke(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:37)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.invoke(ExecutableInvoker.java:104)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.invoke(ExecutableInvoker.java:98)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeTestMethod$7(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:214)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.invokeTestMethod(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:210)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:135)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:66)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$6(NodeTestTask.java:151)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:141)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$9(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:138)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:95)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:41)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$6(NodeTestTask.java:155)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:141)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$9(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:138)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:95)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:41)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$6(NodeTestTask.java:155)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:141)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$9(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:138)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:95)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.submit(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:35)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:57)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestEngine.execute(HierarchicalTestEngine.java:54)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:107)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:88)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.lambda$execute$0(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:54)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.withInterceptedStreams(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:67)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:52)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:114)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:86)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncherSession$DelegatingLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncherSession.java:86)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.SessionPerRequestLauncher.execute(SessionPerRequestLauncher.java:53)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junitplatform.JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor$CollectAllTestClassesExecutor.processAllTestClasses(JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor.java:99)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junitplatform.JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor$CollectAllTestClassesExecutor.access$000(JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor.java:79)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junitplatform.JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor.stop(JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor.java:75)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.SuiteTestClassProcessor.stop(SuiteTestClassProcessor.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:104)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:577)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:36)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:24)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ContextClassLoaderDispatch.dispatch(ContextClassLoaderDispatch.java:33)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ProxyDispatchAdapter$DispatchingInvocationHandler.invoke(ProxyDispatchAdapter.java:94)
    at jdk.proxy1/jdk.proxy1.$Proxy2.stop(Unknown Source)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker$3.run(TestWorker.java:193)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker.executeAndMaintainThreadName(TestWorker.java:129)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker.execute(TestWorker.java:100)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker.execute(TestWorker.java:60)
    at org.gradle.process.internal.worker.child.ActionExecutionWorker.execute(ActionExecutionWorker.java:56)
    at org.gradle.process.internal.worker.child.SystemApplicationClassLoaderWorker.call(SystemApplicationClassLoaderWorker.java:113)
    at org.gradle.process.internal.worker.child.SystemApplicationClassLoaderWorker.call(SystemApplicationClassLoaderWorker.java:65)
    at worker.org.gradle.process.internal.worker.GradleWorkerMain.run(GradleWorkerMain.java:69)
    at worker.org.gradle.process.internal.worker.GradleWorkerMain.main(GradleWorkerMain.java:74)
```

User unit test and Category unit test works fine.